# What was seen in Vishwa-roop of Krishna?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

Krishna showed his Vishwa-roop to Arjun . I want to know what was seen in his vishwa-roop. I have heard that all devtas (inc. Shiva , Brahma) was inside his vishwa-roop.
Is it true ?

Were devis (female deities like Durga , Saraswti etc) also seen in his vishwa-roop ?

Comment: Open Gita and read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Vishwaroopa has Adityas, Vasus, Rudras, Ashwinis and Maruts

O Bhārata, behold the twelve Ādityas, the eight Vasus, the eleven Rudras, the two Aśvinī-kumāras, the forty-nine Maruts and so many other astonishing forms, unwitnessed by anyone before.

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shrimad-bhagavad-gita/d/doc420105.html

2. All of universe is part of Vishwaroopa -

O Guḍākeśa, now behold the entire universe, including all moving and non-moving beings, assembled together in one place within this body of Mine. Whatever else you wish to see is also visible within this universal form.

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shrimad-bhagavad-gita/d/doc420106.html

3. Arjuna see Devas, Brahma and Shiva in the Vishwaroopa -

Arjuna said: O My Lord, within Your divine body I see the demigods and the hosts of living beings. I see Lord Brahmā seated upon his lotus-flower seat, and I see Lord Śiva and all the divine sages and serpents.

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shrimad-bhagavad-gita/d/doc420113.html

4. Arjuna witness the Sun and moon as his eyes and fire from his mouth -

I see that You are without beginning, middle or end. You possess infinite prowess and innumerable arms, and Your eyes are like the sun and the moon. I see fire blazing from Your mouths and the whole universe being scorched by Your radiance.

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shrimad-bhagavad-gita/d/doc420117.html

5. All the gods worships Krishna in wonder -

The eleven Rudras, the twelve Ādityas, the eight Vasus, the Sādhya demigods, the Viśva demigods, the twin Aśvinī-kumāras, the Maruts, Pitṛs, Gandharvas, Yakṣas, Asuras and the Siddhas are all beholding You in wonder.

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shrimad-bhagavad-gita/d/doc420120.html